# Parsing PDF document using itextsharp - missing flattened form field values

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

I create a PDF file by using a template and filling in the form fields. I then flatten the PDF to prevent changes to it. I now have a need to parse the PDF's and get the data from the form fields; however, when I parse the PDF the text where the form field was is missing. It seems I can't reference the field because the PDF was flattened AND parsing the PDF skips the fields where the text was and returns

> First Name:   Last Name:

but the PDF actually has

> First Name: Jane  Last Name: Doe

How can I get the text where the form fields used to be?

## UPDATE

```
Dim text As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

If File.Exists(filename) Then
    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(filename)

    For page As Integer = 1 To pdfReader.NumberOfPages
        Dim strategy As ITextExtractionStrategy = New SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()
        Dim currentText As String = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy)

        currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)))
            text.Append(currentText)
     Next

     pdfReader.Close()

     textBox1.Text = text.ToString()
     textBox1.SelectionStart = 0
End If
```

I can't post the original files due to the information within them BUT I can post 2 sample files that illustrate what I'm doing.

I'm using a template pdf like this... fw4.pdf

I'm then filling it with data and flattening it so it is like this... final_fw4.pdf

When I parse it using the code above I get this... parsed_pdf_text.txt
[view the files](http://dph.state.al.us/rob.keith/)

None of the data is in the parsed text!

Comment: Please show how you do the text parsing. Especially, which text extraction strategy are you using. Furthermore supply a sample PDF file.

Comment: Files and more detail have been added!

Comment: I see you use the simple text extraction strategy. Have you also tried the location text extraction strategy? The simple one assumes that the content stream is already in the correct reading order which in case of form flattening it surely isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis of the issue is incorrect:

> however, when I parse the PDF the text where the form field was is missing

No, it's not missing. It merely is not where you expect it to be. If you search your parsed_pdf_text.txt for "Ja", you'll find the flattened entries all together in one block:

```
Ja
Ja
Ja
8
0
1
16
28
Jane Doe 532 12 1234
100 North Cujo Street
Nome, AK  67201
4 4 9
10
11
Walmart, Nome, AK
WAL666 AB 4321
```

The reason is, as already indicated in a comment to your question, that you use the [SimpleTextExtractionStrategy](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/SimpleTextExtractionStrategy.cs)

```
Dim strategy As ITextExtractionStrategy = New SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()
Dim currentText As String = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy)
```

Have a look at the class comment:

```
 * This renderer keeps track of the current Y position of each string.  If it detects
 * that the y position has changed, it inserts a line break into the output.  If the
 * PDF renders text in a non-top-to-bottom fashion, this will result in the text not
 * being a true representation of how it appears in the PDF.
 * 
 * This renderer also uses a simple strategy based on the font metrics to determine if
 * a blank space should be inserted into the output.
```

The form information flattened into the content is added at the end of the content stream, thus the text appears at the end of the page text.

You might want to use the [LocationTextExtractionStrategy](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/LocationTextExtractionStrategy.cs) instead. Its class comment indicates:

```
 * A text extraction renderer that keeps track of relative position of text on page
 * The resultant text will be relatively consistent with the physical layout that most
 * PDF files have on screen.
 * <br>
 * This renderer keeps track of the orientation and distance (both perpendicular
 * and parallel) to the unit vector of the orientation.  Text is ordered by
 * orientation, then perpendicular, then parallel distance.  Text with the same
 * perpendicular distance, but different parallel distance is treated as being on
 * the same line.
 * <br>
 * This renderer also uses a simple strategy based on the font metrics to determine if
 * a blank space should be inserted into the output.
```

This still is not optimal but in you case maybe better.

> I now have a need to parse the PDF's and get the data from the form fields

If you only have a limited number of forms, you can investigate the position of the original form fields and only parse the text at those field positions. In that case applying the [FilteredRenderListener](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/FilteredRenderListener.cs) in combination with the [RegionTextRenderFilter](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/RegionTextRenderFilter.cs) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Text might be set on page load using Javascript action. But anyway, would love to see a file

Comment: Files and more detail have been added!

Answer (score 1):

This is speculation based on not having a file to look at.

If by flattening, you mean "put the form data in the content", then the data is likely gone in any kind of easily accessible way.  Form data on a page is represented by widget annotations.  To flatten a form, you would take the appearance for a given instance of a widget annotation (or create one) and append to the page content stream to include the PDF code to render the form field, then finally remove the annotation.

Here's what I see in your file - the first page has several content streams.  The last content stream contains this excerpt:

```
Q q Q q 1 0 0 1 501.46 481.92 cm /Xi0 Do Q q Q q 1 0 0 1 500.87 457.9 cm /Xi1 Do Q q Q
```

which is (more or less):

```
grestore
gsave
grestore
gsave
    translate(501.46, 481.92)
    XObject("Xi0")
grestore
gsave
grestore
gsave
    translate(500.87, 457.9)
    XObject("Xi1")
grestore
gsave
grestore
```

Xi0 is object #1 in the file, which is a Form XObject which has the following content stream:

```
q Q /Tx BMC q 0 0 26.03 12.33 re W n q BT 1 0 0 1 8.01 2.93 Tm /HeBo 9 Tf
1 0.59 0 0.11 k (Ja)Tj 0 g ET Q Q EMC
```

which is (more or less):

```
gsave
grestore
BeginMarkedContent("Tx")
gsave
    AddRectangle(0, 0, 26.03, 12.33)
    clip
    newpath
    gsave
        begintext
          TextTranslate(8.01, 2.93)
          SetFont("Helvetica-Bold", 9)
          SetCMYKColor(1, .59, 0, .11)
          DrawText("Ja")
          SetGray(0)
        endtext
    grestore
grestore
EndMarkedContent()
```

Your text is there and it's doing exactly what I had speculated.  The more interesting question is, "why don't I see it when I use iTextSharp to extract the text?  I don't know precisely, since I didn't work on iTextSharp, but I *did* work on Adobe Acrobat and among other things I worked on the text extraction engine that was used for search in Acrobat 1.0, so I know how challenging it can be to extract text from PDF and most products do it wrong or badly or both because of these challenges.  Likely, iTextSharp iterates through the content stream and on any text operator it aggregates the actions and the state (ie, "place this text here in this font and this color and render mode"), but just as likely it is NOT making a recursive call for XObjects and it thus completely missing everything created by flattening the form.

The short answer is most likely a bug in iTextSharp and one worth reporting to them.

Normally, I would point you at my company's tools for doing this, but at present I don't have the "flatten" functionality that you want.  Yet.

If I were you, I would take the approach of writing the code to do the flattening yourself.  Effectively, you would need to iterate the widget annotations and instead of writing their appearance stream into the page contents, you would write actual PDF content.

Also, as a PDF afficianado, this PDF output could be better.  There is no excuse for the empty redundant gsave/grestore pairs nor should there be an ineffectual color change.  Fortunately, these things are benign.

Comment: Flatten as in `pdfStamper.FormFlattening = True`

Comment: Files and more detail have been added!

Comment: *but just as likely it is NOT making a recursive call for XObjects* Since Version 5.0.1 it had been recursing. And that has been quite a number of years ago. More likely it's the choice of extraction strategy of the op. The simple one is not sufficient here.